# c# Get DataTable from BindingSource and edit it

Tags: c#, datasource, bindingsource

I need to make some modifications to a `DataTable`that is connected to a `DataGridView` using a `BindingSource` without altering the grid.

This is my code :

```
dtBallaFroc = new DataTable();
//...Fill the datatable
bindingSource.DataSource = dtBallaFroc;
gridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Later in the code I need to edit the datatable :

```
 DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataTable.Rows[i][5] = 0;
}
```

It works ok this way but it also edit my datagridview, how can I stop this ?

Comment: Dont use a binding source if you dont want it to update the grid view. Use a datatable. Binding source has events which updates the datagridview when the data is changed.

Comment: Why don't you set the `gridView.ReadOnly = true` to stop the DataGridView from being editable

Answer (score 7):

IIRC, you can use DataTable.Copy() and modify it.

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
DataTable copyDt =  dataTable.Copy();
```

Here you do the modifications what do you wanted to do.

Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: But Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees!